# PingPong Program Java Multithreading

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to learn basic concept of Multi Threading.

Why my ping pong program prints only Ping0 & Pong0, Why notify() does not start the Ping Thread which is in Wait state?

public class PingPong implements Runnable {
      String word;

```
  public PingPong(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }

  public void run() {

    synchronized (this) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(word + i);
        try {
          wait(); 
          notifyAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable p1 = new PingPong("ping");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
    t1.start();

    Runnable p2 = new PingPong("pong");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
    t2.start();

  }

}
```

Output

```
ping0
pong0
```

I tried removing wait() and it's printing ping pong till the end of loop. but is this guaranteed that it will print in sequence?

Why wait() followed by notify()  does not ask the ping1 thread to start execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar solution using Thread Pool Executors:

```
public class PingPong implements Runnable {
    String word;
    Lock lock;

    public PingPong(String word, Lock lock) {
        this.word = word;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Received : " + word);
            lock.notifyAll();
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        while(true){
            ex.submit(new PingPong("ping", lock));
            ex.submit(new PingPong("pong", lock));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If you see the jstack, you can see thread-0 and thread-1 are waiting for different lock. That's because your p1 and p2 are different objects, so when you use `synchronized (this)`, they are not competing for the same lock, so notify this way won't work. try use another object as the lock.
2. wait need to run after notify. As when both threads go into waiting stat, no other threads can notify them.

try this code:

```
String word;
Object a;
public PingPong(String word, Object a) {
    this.word = word;
    this.a = a;
}

public void run() {

    synchronized (a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(word + i);
            try {

                a.notifyAll();
                a.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Object a = new Object();
    Runnable p1 = new PingPong("ping", a);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
    t1.start();

    Runnable p2 = new PingPong("pong", a);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
    t2.start();

}
```

Comment: Your solution does not support order of appearing 'ping' first. There is no guarantee (

Answer (score 0):

Below solution based on:

- Java internal API
- order of execution

  ```
  public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SynchronousQueue<String> queue = new SynchronousQueue<>();

      Thread ping = new Thread(new Task(queue, "ping", "ping"));
      ping.setName("ping thread");
      ping.start();

      Thread pong = new Thread(new Task(queue, "pong", "ping"));
      pong.setName("pong thread");
      pong.start();


  }

  private static class Task implements Runnable {
      private SynchronousQueue<String> queue;
      private String command;
      private String step;

      Task(SynchronousQueue<String> queue, String command, String step) {
          this.queue = queue;
          this.command = command;
          this.step = step;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              if (command.equals(step)) {
                  doCommandAndWaitRepeatedly();
              } else {
                  waitAndDoCommandRepeatedly();
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }
      }

      private void doCommandAndWaitRepeatedly() throws InterruptedException {
          while (true) {
              queue.offer(command, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              Thread.sleep(500);
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
          }
      }

      private void waitAndDoCommandRepeatedly() throws InterruptedException {
          while (true) {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
              Thread.sleep(500);
              queue.offer(command, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

```java
class Ping extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {        
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("PING");
            try{
                  sleep(2000);
            }  catch(Exception e){}
        }       
     }
}

class Pong extends Thread
{
    public void run() 
    {
        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("PONG");
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }  catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}

public class PingPong
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        Ping p1=new Ping();
        Pong p2=new Pong();
        p1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);  //super important for proper sequence
        p2.start();  
        p1.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.